# Is there a way to use a Gmail account as a central routing service

Tags: redirect, routes, gmail, send

I manage a voluntary group project that uses one gmail account for all of its interactions. Up til this year there were two users of the account. Now there are three, and we are looking at maybe three more. Madness! We are constantly chasing each other to see who will handle a given message. Would be so much better to route messages to specific accounts for a given person to deal with. But we still need to have a central archive for all incoming and outgoing messages.

I'm looking at the use of redirects, and am trying to 'frame' a broader concept of what to do, and then get a grip on whatever the necessary details are.

Here's what I think I'm trying to do. Some of it is not very clear!
Whether Gmail will work that way is what I don't know.

1. Set up a non-gmail domain, e.g. mymail.org.
2. Within that domain, create six accounts, like info@mymail.org, events@mymail.org, and so on.
3. Set up our existing gmail account to both send and receive mail addressed to each of those six accounts.
4. Have gmail redirect incoming messages based on the incoming address.
5. Have the replies to those messages look like they come from the incoming address. (So that further replies get routed correctly.)
6. Have a copy of each incoming and outgoing message stored on the one gmail account. This is crucial for recordkeeping or oversight.

Am I asking for something feasible? If not, what is?

Incidentally, I tried using the mymail+bit@gmail.com method of routing for a while. Didn't help much.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into Google workspace. I think they must have something along the lines of what you are looking for.